# Raspberry pi 4 stays on but doesnt load/run anything

Tags: pi-4

I have a raspberry pi 4 8gb which is powered by the official raspberry 5V power supply. It also has a 64gb sandisk microSD card and heatsinks. And the OS is the raspberry pi 64bit lite OS
I usually have it plugged in 24/7 as it runs a discord bot and a grafana server. However after a couple of days running, the lights on the board still stay on which makes me think its on however the grafana server and the discord bot both turn off. The only way ive found to turn them back on is to turn off and back on the power supply. I have already replaced the microSD card which didnt help and have tried a new install of the OS.

Does anyone have any information on what could be causing this and how i could get it fixed? Could it be a faulty board?

Comment: Power your pi on with no sd card, do you get anything on screen? Have you read the boot sticky https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151

Comment: Rather than power cycling, have you tried connecting a keyboard and screen to see what's happening? Or ssh into it? Have you checked the log files for any information regarding these grafana/discord services?

Comment: It doesn't respond to ssh however I haven't tried connecting it to a monitor. I will check the log files if I find any and try plugging in a monitor for the next time it breaks.